# Zariski closure of image of a polynomial map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Suppose, $f: \mathbb{C}^1 \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a polynomial map given by $f(t) = (f_1(t), f_2(t),.., f_n(t))$ where $f_i(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]$. Then is it true that the Zariski closure of image of $f$ is simply connected (as a Euclidean subspace $\mathbb{C}^n$). 
I believe this is true that a non-constant parametrized curve in an affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is simply-connected since it cannot have self-intersection. So it does not form a loop inside the curve. But I cannot prove it mathematically.

Comment: "It cannot have self-intersection": yes, it can. Take $f(t)=(t^2-1,t(t^2-1))$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. The image is not simply-connected.

Answer (score 1):

To spell out @abx's comment a bit more: put $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2:y^2=x^3+x^2\}$, and define $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^2$ by $f(t)=(t^2-1).(1,t)$.  Then it is straightforward to check that $f(\mathbb{C})\subseteq X$.  If $(x,y)\in X$ with $x\neq 0$ then it is also straightforward to check that $t=y/x$ is the unique value with $f(t)=(x,y)$.  On the other hand, we have $f^{-1}\{(0,0)\}=\{1,-1\}$.  Thus, the image of $f$ is $X$, which is Zariski closed, and is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ with $1$ and $-1$ identified, so it is not simply connected.